# Unterminated string literal.ts(1002)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I tried to add "react-native-css-gradient" but I got this error.

```
import Gradient from 'react-native-css-gradient`; // Here <--- Unterminated string literal.ts(1002) 

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Image,} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
     return (
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have accidentally put in a bad backtick character instead of a single quote.

backtick: `
single quote: '

That first line should be:

```
import Gradient from 'react-native-css-gradient';
```

Should be a quick fix.